# Error FPDF_Code128->__construct('P', 'mm', Array)

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

Espero me puedan ayudar, tengo este error, antes todo iba muy bien, pero hoy por la mañana me sale este error que no eh podido solucionar.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot call constructor in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vpv-v1.0/boot/printed/fpdf184/code128.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vpv-v1.0/boot/printed/barcode.php(12): FPDF_Code128->__construct('P', 'mm', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vpv-v1.0/boot/printed/fpdf184/code128.php on line 19

```
<?php
     if ($_GET['sku']) {

 define('FPDF_FONTPATH','fpdf184/font/');
 require('fpdf184/code128.php');

$pdf = new FPDF_Code128('P','mm', array(80,90));
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,-90);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',8);    //Letra Arial, negrita (Bold), tam. 20
$textypos = 0;


$pdf->Cell(60,$textypos,"Falcon Tienda.",0,0,"C");
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',8);
$textypos+=5;

$pdf->setX(5);
$pdf->Code128(4,13,$_GET['sku'],73,10);
  
$textypos+=25;
$pdf->Cell(70,$textypos,$_GET['sku'],0,0,"C");    

$pdf->output();                             
     }else{
   echo "vacio";
     }//list

?>
```

**estoy usando FPDF, ya actualize a la version mas reciente de fpdf pero aun asi, sigue el error**